# Getting confused by MySQL subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to learn how to do subqueries, and I'm really confused at what's wrong with this simple example.

My first try was

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM my_table);
```

but that didn't work (I guess because I need a temporary table?) so I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(items)
FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table) AS items;
```

Why do I get the following:

> 1054: Unknown column 'items' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because in this example `items` is a table (as it is an alias), not a column.  Simplest solution is to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table) AS items
```

Aggregate functions (IE: COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, etc) only work on column references, but some accept [table].* as a parameter.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that works? I'm trying something similar and it gives me a syntax error near `*`...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Post the query you're attempting to use.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(tab.*) FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) AS tab;`

Comment: Also, are you sure that the alias is in fact a table? If I try a self-join (`SELECT COUNT(tab.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) AS tab JOIN tab tab2 ON tab.id = tab2.id;`) I get told that `tab` doesn't exist (even though it's a temporary table)...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because you can't reference a derived table (temp table is something entirely different) more than once if it hasn't been declared using the `WITH` clause (not supported by MySQL).

Comment: @Mehrdad: My MySQL 5.1.x doesn't support the table alias in the COUNT, see the updated answer for what to use.  Some databases do support using the table reference (real or alias).

Comment: But I *do* need to reference `items` -- COUNT(*) is pretty much the only thing you can do with `*` (short of a plain `SELECT *` instead). What if I want to say `COUNT(ISNULL(items.bar))`? Is there no way to reference the generated table inside my SELECT clause?

Comment: @Mehrdad: There's only one table in the example -- there's no need to distinguish.  `COUNT(items.*)` doesn't work, but have you tested `COUNT(items.bar)`?

Comment: I guess that works, but it's not really doing what I need because it still doesn't let me reference the created table from *inside* a SELECT clause's subquery. i.e. `SELECT (SELECT * FROM baz) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) AS baz` doesn't work, since it says `baz` isn't a table in my database. (You could argue that I should post that as a new question I guess...)

Comment: *"but it's not really doing what I need"*. We haven't really understood what you really need that a subquery can't solve.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The issue to me is that it's not clear what you believe should be happening.  Why would you do a subselect on baz?  It won't work because you can only return one column from a subselect...

Comment: If you want to have something like: `SELECT COUNT(tab.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) AS tab JOIN tab tab2 ON tab.id = tab2.id;` then this can be done with `WITH` clause which unfortunately MySQL doesn't have or with a query liek this (where some code is duplicated): `SELECT COUNT(tab.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) AS tab JOIN (SELECT * FROM foo) AS tab2 ON tab.id = tab2.id;`